# recreate encoding mixup in mysql table

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding, mojibake

I have an sql table where a column has `utf8_unicode_ci` encoding, but the table itself has `latin1_swedish_ci` encoding (as reported under `Row Statistics` in `Structure` tab of `phpMyAdmin`).

The PHP webapp that accesses the database displays Japanese text correctly, but inside `phpMyAdmin` everything is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). The webapp (correctly) displays the Japanese text `Xで有名な`, but in `phpMyAdmin` it is `Xã¦ã‚™æœ‰åãª` (`hex()` output is `312E2058C3A3C281C2A6C3A3E2809AE284A2C3A6C593E280B0C3A5C290C28DC3A3C281C2AA`).

The app that was used to generate the data in the table is now broken, but I need to add a few new records. How can I recreate the mojibake found in the table?

I tried to reproduce the mojibake with python:

```
def rev_engineer(utf8):
    mojibake = utf8.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
    print(mojibake)

rev_engineer('Xで有名な')
# output:    Xã¦ãæåãª
# should be: Xã¦ã‚™æœ‰åãª
```

This is obviously very similar, but not quite there. I then tried looping through every possible encoding listed in python's documentation, and encoding/decoding every possible combination, but that did not come up with a match, either. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: can you run **select hex(column_name) from your table where id=<...>;**

Comment: @EchoMike444 312E2058C3A3C281C2A6C3A3E2809AE284A2C3A6C593E280B0C3A5C290C28DC3A3C281C2AA

Comment: It seems to be worse than Mojibake -- "double encoding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure my character will be interpreted as UTF8 sequence

```
test> set names utf8 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

check that i have 2 bytes for **é**

```
test> select hex(binary('é')) ;
+-------------------+
| hex(binary('é')) |
+-------------------+
| C3A9              |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

checking i have the same value

```
test ]> select convert(binary(convert(convert(unhex('312E2058C3A3C281C2A6C3A3E2809AE284A2C3A6C593E280B0C3A5C290C28DC3A3C281C2AA') using utf8 ) using latin1 )) using utf8 );
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert(binary(convert(convert(unhex('312E2058C3A3C281C2A6C3A3E2809AE284A2C3A6C593E280B0C3A5C290C28DC3A3C281C2AA') using utf8 ) using latin1 )) using utf8 ) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1. Xで有名な                                                                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

by copy/paste the output string  , i can reverse the process

```
test > select hex(convert (convert(binary('1. Xで有名な  ') using latin1 ) using utf8 )) ;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(convert (convert(binary('1. Xで有名な') using latin1 ) using utf8 )) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 312E2058C3A3C281C2A6C3A3E2809AE284A2C3A6C593E280B0C3A5C290C28DC3A3C281C2AA      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you have a few rows to insert you insert your rows with pphpmyadmin and if it does not work directly via the command mysql .

If you want to use python you can use this module :
  https://pypi.org/project/mysql-latin1-codec/

Comment: Note:  That first long CONVERT(...) can be used in an `UPDATE` for "fixing" the data in the table.  This is an example of "double encoding".  More discussion of that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  Do not use python conversions, use SQL.